# How can I get how much camera has panned in three.js

Tags: three.js

In three.js how can I know how much the camera has panned?

I need to keep an SVG layer on top of the three.js canvas aligned with the 3D objects as I pan the camera with orbitControls.

I use [svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) for the SVG layer, and it works great for zooming.

For panning, I currently use the 'change' event and follow the camera accordingly like this (SVG and three.js setup omitted):

```
var unproject = function(vector3d, transform) {
    var app = this.app;

    var v = vector3d.clone();
    v.project( app.three.camera );

    v.x = Math.round( (   v.x + 1 ) * three_element.offsetWidth  / 2 );
    v.y = Math.round( ( - v.y + 1 ) * three_element.offsetHeight / 2 );
    v.z = 0;

    if (transform) {
    var matrix = svg.node.getCTM().inverse()
    var p =      svg.node.createSVGPoint()
    p.x = v.x; p.y = v.y
    p = p.matrixTransform(matrix)
    v.x = p.x
    v.y = p.y
    }
    return v;
}

var panBy = function(d){ panZoom.panBy(d) };

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, document.getElementById('canvas') );

var ref = unproject(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(e) {
    var curr = unproject(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
    var dist = curr.clone().sub(ref)
    panBy(dist)
    ref = curr;
} );
```

But obviously the SVG panning lags a bit behind the 3D window panning. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you please try to call `app.three.camera.updateMatrixWorld()` before you invoke `Vector3.project()`? The mentioned lag could happen because the camera matrices are not up-to-date.

Comment: @Mugen87 that seems to have solved the lag, thanks